# Entity not found in Advanced Fine->Edit Columns drop down

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

Having an issue with Advanced Find->Edit Columns.

I have a Lead and Opportunity entity.  They both have a 1:N relationship to the same custom entity (Response).  Display options for relationships are "Use Plural Name."

I go to Advanced Find.  I select Lead (or Opportunity) in "Look For."  I can select Response and then its attributes.  Runs fine.

However, when I go to Edit Columns->Add Columns, I do not see Response in the drop down.

Hopefully someone out there has an idea of why this might be.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that Lead could have several related Responses (1:N relationship). But CRM can show only one, and cannot choose which one from related Responses to show. I case you will create view for Responses, you will be able to add fields from either related Leads or Opportunities.